# Questions about Mesos Linux container and Docker

Tags: docker, lxc, mesos

1. The Apache Mesos page describes that Mesos enables task isolation through "Linux Containers". What container technology is this, LxC?
2. Does "native Docker support" mean that the above container technology can we swapped to Docker? What does it mean when Mesos states that Docker can be used either as an Executor or a Task? If Docker is used as an Executor, doesn't it mean that there should be a "Docker Framework" somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually mesos supports several containerizer:

1. Docker (see http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/)
2. Mesos Containerizer (default)
3. Custom External Containerizer (see http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/external-containerizer/)

Native docker support in my understanding refers to the support for many of the docker specific options (see for example the configuration options here: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/)

Short Update: Please note that option 3 (external containerizer) is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I guess what I am really asking is information about the 2. Mesos Containerizer. What container is this, or is this some Mesos own container implementation? Documentation anywhere?

Comment: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/. Strangely this is not linked on the normal documentation page... I will follow up on that and open a Jira...

Answer (score -2):

Know what a Virtual Machine (like VMWare or Virtual PC) is? Docker is something like a much more 'lightweight' virtual machine (of course more superior, but let's keep it simple here). Further information can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29 and here https://www.docker.com/.

Comment: Sure I know what Docker is, but I think your answer is not directly valid here

Comment: So maybe you'd like to rephrase your question here.